# Arrays in type script

Tags: arrays, class, object, typescript

I am finding difficulty declaring array in typescript and accessing it.

below is the code working for me

```
class Book {
    public BookId: number;
    public Title: string;
    public Author: string;
    public Price: number;
    public Description: string;
}

class dataservice {
    getproducts() {
        var bk = new Book();
        bk.Author = "vamsee";
        bk.BookId = 1;
        var bks: Book[] = [bk,bk];

        return bks.length;
    }
}

var ds = new dataservice();
var button = document.createElement('button');

button.onclick = function () {     
    alert(ds.getproducts().toString());
}

document.body.appendChild(button);
```

When I change my code as below it fails when trying to assign value to array item.

```
var bks: Book[] = new Book[2];
bks[0].Author = "vamsee";
bks[0].BookId = 1;
return bks.length;
```

For me to add object in a loop I have to do it the second way.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

This is a very c# type of code:

```
var bks: Book[] = new Book[2];
```

In Javascript / Typescript you don't allocate memory up front like that, and that means something completely different. This is how you would do what you want to do:

```
var bks: Book[] = [];
bks.push(new Book());
bks[0].Author = "vamsee";
bks[0].BookId = 1;
return bks.length;
```

Now to explain what `new Book[2];` would mean. This would actually mean that call the new operator on the value of Book[2]. e.g.:

```
Book[2] = function (){alert("hey");}
var foo = new Book[2]
```

and you should see hey. [Try it](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground/#src=class%20Book%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20public%20BookId:%20number;%0A%20%20%20%20public%20Title:%20string;%0A%20%20%20%20public%20Author:%20string;%0A%20%20%20%20public%20Price:%20number;%0A%20%20%20%20public%20Description:%20string;%0A%7D%0A%0ABook%5B2%5D%20=%20function%20%28%29%7Balert%28%22hey%22%29;%7D%0Avar%20foo%20=%20new%20Book%5B2%5D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20)

Comment: Update: The 'new Book[2]' will give an error in TS 0.9 : `No longer accept "new number[]"` : https://typescript.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Known%20breaking%20changes%20between%200.8%20and%200.9 so the compiler will tell you that it is wrong :)

Answer (score 16):

You can also do this as well (shorter cut) instead of having to do instance declaration.  You do this in JSON instead.

```
class Book {
    public BookId: number;
    public Title: string;
    public Author: string;
    public Price: number;
    public Description: string;
}

var bks: Book[] = [];

 bks.push({BookId: 1, Title:"foo", Author:"foo", Price: 5, Description: "foo"});   //This is all done in JSON.
```

Answer (score -1):

A cleaner way to do this:

```
class Book {
    public Title: string;
    public Price: number;
    public Description: string;

    constructor(public BookId: number, public Author: string){}
}
```

Then

```
var bks: Book[] = [
    new Book(1, "vamsee")
];
```

Comment: But you are not initializing the data in constructor, will it initialized automatically?

Comment: Yes, it does. See the "Parameter properties" section of http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html