# How to push item to [string] in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I want to add items to [string].
But the following code fails at param.push statement.

EDIT

```
declare var sqlitePlugin:any;
var query: string = `SELECT * FROM items `;

var param: [string];

if (options['limit']) {
  var limit = options['limit'];
  query = query + " LIMIT ? ";
  param.push(String(limit));
}

if (options['offset']) {
  var offset = options['offset'];
  query = query + " OFFSET ? ";
  param.push(String(offset));
}

sqlitePlugin.openDatabase({name: 'Items.db', key: 'Password', location: 'default'}, (db) =>  {
  db.transaction((tx)=> {
    tx.execQuery(query, param, (resultSet)=>{
    this.items = [];
      for(let i = 0; i < resultSet.rows.length; i++) {
        var item: Item = new Item();
        item.code = resultSet.rows.item(i).item_code;
        item.name = resultSet.rows.item(i).item_name;
        this.items.push(item);
      }
      callback(this.items);
    } );
  }
});
```

Sorry to ask this very basic question but I'm struggling for 2 days..
Please give me any hint or link.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Look at [Arrays in type script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16233266/arrays-in-type-script) , may be this will help you.

Comment: @tomo, it'd be better not to change the scope of the question. The original question you asked, I answered. You probably ought to ask a separate question for this particular issue you're facing now :)

Comment: okay, thanks @gdgr

Comment: no problem @tomo, I requested an edit to the question but feel free to take it back to revision 2 :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try:

```
var param: string[] = [];
```

[Check this snippet out, it shows the desired result.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=var%20param%3A%20string%5B%5D%20%3D%20%5B%5D%3B%0D%0Aparam.push('yeah')%3B%0D%0Aalert(param)%3B)
The issue is you're just not initialising the variable `param`, so `.push` doesn't exist for `undefined`.

Also you weren't declaring the array properly (see difference above). There are two ways to do so, taken from TypeScript's documentation:

> TypeScript, like JavaScript, allows you to work with arrays of values.
>   Array types can be written in one of two ways. In the first, you use
>   the type of the elements followed by [] to denote an array of that
>   element type:

```
let list: number[] = [1, 2, 3];
```

> The second way uses a generic array type, Array:

```
let list: Array<number> = [1, 2, 3];
```

[And here is the relevant documentation on TS site](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html)

Comment: I tried `var param : string[]` but it doesn't work because param valuable is set to a function and syntax error occurs 'Argument of type string[] is not assignable to parameter of type [string]...'

Comment: You're welcome. What about the updated code where you got the error you just mentioned?

Comment: I got syntax error at `tx.execQuery(query, param, (resultSet)=>{`.

Comment: But I only see this line declaring `param`.. `var param: [string];`

Comment: sorry, its typo. currently it's `var param: string[];`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113046/discussion-between-gdgr-and-tomo).

Answer (score 0):

You can use either of the below 2 syntaxes to define a string array in typescript:

**Using general array syntax:**

```
var param: string[] = [];
```

**Using Generics syntax:**

```
var param: Array<string> = [];
```

Comment: thanks. but as @gdgr 's answer, both sentences cause same syntax error I wrote in his comment.

Comment: You need to initialise an array variable atleast to an emoty array in order to access any methods on it, irrespective of whether you use TypeScript or JavaScript